# Python: Have to press ctrl+c to get an result

Tags: python, sockets, ports

I am trying to create a python script to check if an port is available or not. Below is a piece of the code (not the total script).

But when I run the script the terminal shows no output, when I press ctrl + c I get an single result of the script, when I hit ctrl+c again I get the second result. When the script is done it finally quits...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import socket
from itertools import islice

resultslocation = '/tmp/'
f2name = 'positives.txt'
f3name = 'ip_addresses.txt'
f4name = 'common_ports.txt'

#Trim down the positive results to only the IP addresses and scan them with the given ports in the common_ports.txt file

with open(resultslocation + f2name, 'r') as f2, open(resultslocation + f3name, 'w') as f3:
    hits = f2.read()
    list = re.findall(r'name = (.+).', hits)
    for items in list:
        ip_addresses = socket.gethostbyname(items)
        with open(resultslocation + f4name, 'r') as f4:
            for items in f4:
                ports = int(items)
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                try:
                    s.connect((ip_addresses, ports))
                    s.shutdown(2)
                    print 'port', ports, 'on', ip_addresses, 'is open'
                except:
                    print 'port', ports, 'on', ip_addresses, 'is closed'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the results you're getting? -- I'm guessing that `s.connect` blocks execution until you connect to something, but you're failing to connect, so it's just waiting there.  When you hit `ctrl-c` you trow the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception which is handled in your (**bare!**) exception handler.

Comment: You might want to look into [getdefaulttimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getdefaulttimeout) and [setdefaulttimeout]( http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) and finally [create_connection](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection)

Comment: A few other things.  Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a builtin and makes your code confusing (and possibly buggy).  Also, it's not the best idea to use the same variable name in both an inner and outter loop to represent different data (`items` in this case).  Finally, the fact that you pluralize `ports` and `items` is misleading, as if those variables actually represented multiple values, your `ports = int(items)` would raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will edit my variable names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, sockets are created in blocking mode.

So in general it is recommended to call `settimeout()` before calling `connect()` or pass a timeout parameter to `create_connection()` and use that instead of connect. Since you code already captures exceptions, the first option is easy to implement;

```
with open(resultslocation + f2name, 'r') as f2, open(resultslocation + f3name, 'w') as f3:
    hits = f2.read()
    list = re.findall(r'name = (.+).', hits)
    for items in list:
        ip_addresses = socket.gethostbyname(items)
        with open(resultslocation + f4name, 'r') as f4:
            for items in f4:
                ports = int(items)
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.settimeout(1.0) # Set a timeout (value in seconds).
                try:
                    s.connect((ip_addresses, ports))
                    s.shutdown(2)
                    print 'port', ports, 'on', ip_addresses, 'is open'
                except:
                    # This will alse catch the timeout exception.
                    print 'port', ports, 'on', ip_addresses, 'is closed'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! `s.settimeout(1.0) # Set a timeout (value in seconds)` is the solution!